# Can I send a OneDrive File Request using Microsoft's Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

[Microsoft OneDrive allows you to send a "file request"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-file-request-f54aa7f8-2589-4421-b351-d415fc3b83af) so others can send you very large files without needing a OneDrive account themselves.
I'm wanting to use an API (probably [Microsoft Graph API)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onedrive-concept-overview)) to automatically create file requests on a user's behalf, and delete them later too.

Is it possible to create a OneDrive file request via an API? If so, where is that documented?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that feature is not available yet. I see a feature request for the same in MS Graph [user voice page](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41380951-provide-api-on-creating-request-files-link). Please upvote/comment on the same so that the feature team will get better visibility.